# Wordpress: New user role which is ONLY allowed to manage media

Tags: users, user-roles

I would like to have a new user role (or restrict a role which is already available from Wordpress) which can only manage media (upload, delete pictures etc.) in the wordpress backend - every other possibility in the wordpress backend is not allowed and not visible.

Used user role editor without success

Comment: If I'm reading this right, the only capability your Media Manager role would require is [`upload_files`](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/#upload_files).

Comment: delete_posts also for deleting files! thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in @Harrison's answer. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [add_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) function should give you what you're looking for. Here's an example of using it to add a new role that allows the user to upload and delete media:

```
function wpse413985_add_role(){

/* Check if the role already exists, since we 
don't need to add it again every time the site loads. */
  if ( !get_role( 'wpse413985_media_manager' ) ){
    
     add_role( 
      'wpse413985_media_manager', 
      __( 'Media Manager', 'wpse413985-textdomain' ),
      array( 
        'upload_files' => true,
        'delete_posts' => true
      ));

  }
}

add_action( 'init', "wpse413985_add_role" );
```

A user with the 'media manager' role in this example will see a link to the media library but none of the other admin screens. The `delete posts` capability is necessary to delete pictures because media files count as 'posts' in wordpress. The user won't be able to delete regular posts because they can't visit that part of the admin.

This function would go in a theme's `functions.php`. However, you could also put it in a plugin. In that case, instead of hooking to the `init` action, you could use [register_activation_hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/). That would eliminate the need for the conditional.

Comment: Thanks Harrison, didnt know that delete posts was necessary too!